# Thinkpad Yoga "Disk I/O Error" (Linux)

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, thinkpad, io

My machine is sporadically remounting the SSD read-only due to a "Disk I/O Error". This seems only to happen when I connect to the laptop to a power source or after resuming from suspend. The SSD itself is doing fine according SMART testing.

The problem is still present when running mainline kernel 3.16, however it seems to vanish when I disable SATA link power management (I have not experienced the error after disabling it, while it had previously appeared quite regularly). Since this is clearly an unsatisfying situation, I was wondering whether you have any suggestions that allow me to run Linux with SATA power management enabled.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to SU.  As-is this "question" is way too broad, and shows little signs of research effort.  aisde ofmr h upgrading your kernel, what diagnostics have you tried? ie: Maybe the SSD is broken. Check the SMART status and/or try replacing it.  If you suspect TLP, stop using it for a while.

Comment: Hi Techie007. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue, although I believe it only happens whilst I'm running VirtualBox. You didn't mention it, but does this match your situation? In terms of diagnostics, I've run the full suite of SMART tools, as well as a full system health check from the BIOS - everything comes back fine. What SSD are you using? Mines a Crucial MX100, firmware version MU01, which I believe is the latest (having spoken with Crucial tech support)

Comment: A bit more information would be nice. Having your distro/version in the question rather than the tags would be nice, as would your *precise* laptop model and SSD model. More really *is* more sometimes

Comment: Hi griechiec. No, this is running Linux Mint without any virtualization. It appears that running the latest kernel + disabling SATA power management then the crashes are gone. However, now the laptop does not go to sleep anymore (or rather, it randomly wakes up, which is quite troublesome). I will attempt yet another clean re-install at some point in the future...

Comment: Hi Journeyman Geek. As mentioned in the post, the laptop is a "Thinkpad Yoga", the distro is the latest "Linux Mint", and I am running "mainline kernel 3.16". The SSD is a "SAMSUNG MZ7TTD256HAFV-000L9".